# Deshabilitar el diseño de bootstrap a <fieldset>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer que bootstrap no edite el `<fieldset>` con su diseño, para que me deje a mí editarlo de forma independiente con css.

bootstrap le quita los bordes al `<textfield>` y ancha el `<legend>`. Yo lo quisiera con su diseño por default.

Ocupo bootstrap para otras cosas en la misma página y es por eso que quitar el link de bootstrap no me resulta.

Comment: Tan solo añade tus hojas de estilo con mayor [especifidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Es que no tengo un estilo para el fieldset. Lo quiero como esta: por defecto, y que bootstrap no lo cambie o que pueda hacer algun tipo de metodo para que la etiqueta no tome ningun nada de ningun css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es eliminar las ocurrencias de filed set en el archivo bootstrap. Ahi no falla.
Otra es sobreescribir los valores que establece bootstrap para este control que son
fieldset:disabled y fieldset, y en ellos colocar revert

```
fieldset:disabled{
    pointer-events: revert;
    opacity: revert;
}

fieldset {
    min-width: revert;
    padding: revert;
    margin: revert;
    border: revert;
}
```

Comment: gracias. Me sirvio por completo